# Is there any investing strategy to take advantage of Volatility drag?

Tags: united-states

Besides shorting leveraged ETFs.

Say a leveraged investment in an asset suffers drag and it goes down even if the asset is flat. How do I capitalize on this? Is shorting leveraged ETFs the only option?

Comment: In addition to shorting the underlying, you can buy puts if it has options.

Comment: Besides leveraged ETFs?

Comment: I have no idea what your cryptic 3 word question means.  Taking a guess, yes, you can buy pus on anything that you want.

Comment: You don't know what leveraged etf decay is?

Comment: Besides ETF drag?